# How to retrieve context from instantiated POCO class?

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, repository-pattern, entity-framework-5

I am using `Code-First` along with `Entity Framework 5` and the `Repository Pattern`.

I need to get the context from inside some extension methods to access other entities that are not accessible through properties.

Example:

```
public static class MyClassExtensions
{
    public static void DoSomething(this MyClass mClass)
    {
        // This is what I want to do
        // GetContextSomeWay() is what I need
        // GetRepository is method from my context
        mClass.GetContextSomeWay().GetRepository<SomeRepository>().Where(...);
    }
}

public class MyService
{
    public void DoSomethingOnService(int id)
    {
        MyContext ctx = new MyContext();
        MyClass cl = ctx.GetRepository<MyClass>().Single(c => c.Id == id);
        cl.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

I thought about two solutions.

1. Pass the context as a parameter to the extension method
2. Set the context to each entity using the `ObjectMaterialized` event

Even though the first approach would work without much hassle, I can't stop thinking that this is not a good practice.

With the second, besides the work of adding a new property to each one of my classes, I was wondering if that could become a performance issue. Is this an overconcern, or is this valid?

Are there any other solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding Unity and placing your repository there can be a solution.
You just have a container where the things live that you need, 
at best at the composition root.

You can access those via the Unity container then.

Here is a very good tutorial which shows the techniques needed:
[Jason Dollinger on MVVM](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/2650).
It is mainly about MVVM, but shows the usage of unity, too.

The sourcecode is available here: 
[MVVM Demo client source code](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/2689)

Here is more information on those:

[Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/)

[Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. My solutions wouldn't be ideal as I supposed, right?

Comment: You can decouple your servicelayer creation from it's use, just as you want to do. It is really easy to use and very comfortable. Have a look into it, I believe you are going to like it.

Comment: You are welcome. Forgot to mention the important point that you can even defer the creation of the servicelayer to where you access it.